# JavaScript: TypeError: xyz is not a function when calling the function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to come up with a page on which, when user clicks a file button on the page, I try to execute the JS on the page. And I am trying to use OOP / class so hopefully it can be reused later. Here is my test code:

```
// This is the "class". 
function BearUpload() {
    // some values will go here...    
}

// Add a few functions
BearUpload.prototype.function1 = function () {
    console.log("function1 called");
}    

BearUpload.prototype.handleFileSelect = function (evt) {
    console.log("handleFileSelect called");

    this.function1();
}


var myBear = new BearUpload(); // Create a global variable for the test


$(document).ready(function () {
    var some_condition_goes_here = true;
    if (some_condition_goes_here) {
        $("#my-file-select-button").change(myBear.handleFileSelect);
    }
});
```

However, it gets error like:

```
TypeError: this.function1 is not a function

this.function1();
```

Any idea about this?

Thanks!

Comment: `this` is not the `this` you expect it to be when `myBear.handleFileSelect` is called. jQuery changes it to the DOM element which triggered the `change` event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind `myBear` to your `change` eventListener

In general when you access `this` from `handleFileSelect`, `this` refers to the html element.
 i.e. `this` =  `<input type="file" id="my-file-select-button">`

```
$("#my-file-select-button").change(myBear.handleFileSelect.bind(myBear));
```

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

[MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call function1 on DOM object but you have to call on jQuery object

```
$(this).function1();
```

Comment: `myBear` is a jQuery object? O.o

Comment: `this` = `<input type="file" id="my-file-select-button">`

Answer (score 0):

That's because when bound as a handler to jQuery events, **this** would refer to the element on which the event is triggered.

I would rather change your code like this

```
// Create only one global variable for your app
var APP = {};

// Create class using immediate function/closure
APP.BearUpload = (function(){

//declare private variables here

// Constructor
var bearUpload = function() {
    // some values will go here...    
}

// Add a few functions
bearUpload.prototype.function1 = function () {
    console.log("function1 called");
}    

bearUpload.prototype.handleFileSelect = function (evt) {
    console.log("handleFileSelect called");

    this.function1();
}

return bearUpload;
}());



APP.myBear = new APP.BearUpload(); 


$(document).ready(function () {
    var some_condition_goes_here = true;
    if (some_condition_goes_here) {
        $("#my-file-select-button").change(function(e){
           // do something with event 'e'
           APP.myBear.handleFileSelect.call(APP.myBear, e);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

do not use "this", it is confusing some time.

```
BearUpload.prototype ={
     function1:function(){
         var self = this;
         ...

     },
     handleFileSelect:function(e){
        var self = this;
        ...

     }

}
```